# How to set links clickable in android app?

Tags: java, android, string, hyperlink

I'm trying to set a String clickable if it contains a link, I extract the string from a file. I have the following code, but it doesn't seems to work, it doesn't let me click the link. This code is inside a fragment if that is a problem. Could somebody tell me how to do it?

```
text.setText(challenge);
text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on a piece of the text (not the whole `TextView`), you can use `Html` or `Linkify` (both create links that open urls, though, not a callback in the app).

### `Linkify`

Use a string resource like:

```
<string name="links">Here is a link: http://www.stackoverflow.com</string>
```

Then in a textview:

```
text.setText(R.string.links);
Linkify.addLinks(text, Linkify.ALL);
```

### `Html`

Using `Html.fromHtml`:

```
<string name="html">Here you can put html &lt;a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"&gt;Link!&lt;/&gt;</string>
```

Then in your textview:

```
text.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.html)));
```